# Where to find Microsoft .NET (C#) BCL reference, what classes are available in BCL packages?

Tags: c#, base-class-library

Some classes such as [System.HashCode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.hashcode?view=net-6.0) are only available in recent .NET/.NET Standard versions. In the case of HashCode, its is available as of .NET Standard 2.1. However if you include the [Microsoft.Bcl.HashCode](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.HashCode/) nuget package, this class can be used in .NET Standard 2.0.

I could not find a complete list of:

1. The BCL packages that are available
2. What classes / features they provide
3. To which .NET target framework (.NET Standard, .NET Framework ...) versions can the BCL package be added

Essentially, the question is: How do I know that a particular class is available for an older .NET via a BCL package? (... and what is the package name?)

Comment: Look at github.  https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=microsoft.bcl

Comment: @JayBuckman Thanks, that link is helpful. However it does not list the classes within the packages. It also includes unrelated packages.

Comment: If you pick a package, and click the Open in NuGet Package Explorer, you can access the .xml files in lib/<net version> that contain a description of the functions in each package which might be of use.

Comment: @JayBuckman I am aware of how to check the contents of nuget packages. I am asking if there is a *reference* or some other way to get at the information easily.